# How to make a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression:

$$ 9b^2c^2-84abce+36a^2e^2~$$

As it stands this is not a perfect square. Please how do I make it into a perfect square by placing conditions on the product $ae$?  Thanks.

Edit: I would like to get something of the form $$(A*bc)^2$$ preferably.

Comment: Just comeplete the square and you should have have $-48abce$ left over.

Comment: What to do after completing the square?

Comment: FYI:  The reason I, for one, am not answering this is that you apparently didn't give this a moment's thought before posting.  I infer this from the presence of the expressions $bc$ and $ae$, either of which could just as easily have been a single variable.

Comment: @WillO: Sorry about that. Could you please take a look at it. Let's denote $bc=X, ae = Y$. Then we would have $$ 9X^2-84XY+36Y^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $(3b-6ae)^2=9b^2c^2-36abce+36a^2e^2$

Comment: thanks....please a little more help.

Comment: Though, with this, it means that "the conditions on the product $ae$ would be $ae=0$? Or are you thinking of trying to develop it further.

Comment: I'm thinking of developing it further.